# Problem when deploying Qt app on Raspberry Pi 4 (Could not queue DRM page flip on screen HDMI1 (Invalid argument))

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I've compiled Qt5.15.0 and set up cross-compiler on my host machine (Ubuntu 20.04) and managed to cross-compile a simple Hello World app for my Raspberry Pi 4, however, when I deploy and run it (tried both on Qt Creator and in terminal) I get `Could not queue DRM page flip on screen HDMI1 (Invalid argument)` I use latest Raspbian image and tried both with lite and full desktop versions.

There are some solutions suggesting to set the environment variables;

```
QT_QPA_EGLFS_ALWAYS_SET_MODE=1
QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_ATOMIC=1
```

But I had no luck with setting them.

I don't know where the problem is, I'm very new to Qt.

Answer (score 2):

For those who has the same problem here is how I solved;

Somehow I discovered that Raspberry Pi does not set the environment variable `QT_QPA_EGLFS_ALWAYS_SET_MODE`. You can check that by typing

```
printenv QT_QPA_EGLFS_ALWAYS_SET_MODE
```

or

```
echo $QT_QPA_EGLFS_ALWAYS_SET_MODE
```

in both cases, you should see `1` as a result if you've set it so.

However I got no response when I typed them.

Then I went and opened .profile and added

```
QT_QPA_EGLFS_ALWAYS_SET_MODE=1
```

at the end of the file and rebooted the system. Finally there it was, when I echoed the variable it returned 1, and my programs now work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks! BTW I had to type `export QT_QPA_EGLFS_ALWAYS_SET_MODE=1`

Answer (score 0):

The variables should be set in:

```
/etc/default/qt
```

See [QTBUG-72539](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72538?focusedCommentId=526636&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-526636) in the Qt bug tracking.